# What are all the possible endings and how do you get to them?

Tags: papers-please

In Papers, Please there are 20 possible endings. Does anyone have some sort of flow chart that goes through all the endings and the decisions that need to be made to get to that ending?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a brief summary of the 20 endings:

1. Run into debt.
2. Let your family die of sickness
3. Give the investigator the coded Ezic documents on day 12.
4. Accept the Ezic Gift, but don't let the second Ezic agent pass.
5. Kill an innocent person with the rifle. (Silver Key)
6. Shoot an innocent person with the tranquilizer gun (Gold Key)
7. Kill a guard with the rifle. (Silver Key)
8. Shoot a guard with the tranquilizer gun (Gold Key)
9. Kill the man in red on day 23 with the rifle. (Silver Key)
10. Shoot the man in red on day 23 with the tranquilizer gun (Gold Key)
11. Have unauthorized hangings on the wall during inspection after being warned previously.
12. Arrest Shae on day 25 to get this ending on day 26.
13. Don't work with Ezic, and stop them from blowing up your booth on day 31, but let them blow up the wall.
14. Work with Ezic, but stop them from blowing up the wall on day 31.
15. Work with Ezic, but kill them after they have blown up the wall on day 31.
16. Escape to Obristan
17. Work sometimes with Ezic, but stop them from blowing up the wall and your booth.
18. Escape to Obristan with your whole family
19. Work with Ezic and let them blow up the wall on day 31.
20. Don't work with Ezic and stop them from blowing up the wall on day 31.

More details are available on the [Papers Please Wiki](https://papersplease.fandom.com/wiki/Endings)

Comment: For more details, [see here](https://papersplease.fandom.com/wiki/Endings).